# Devise issue with LDAP Auth in Prod Only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm on Rails 5.2 and I have devise with LDAP setup and working in Development. Deploying to prod with capistrano though it errors out when put my username and password in. I get a nomethod error in devise::sessions::create. undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. This is the section that errors out:

```
end
    ldap_options = params
    ldap_config["ssl"] = :simple_tls if ldap_config["ssl"] === true
    ldap_options[:encryption] = ldap_config["ssl"].to_sym if ldap_config["ssl"]

    @ldap = Net::LDAP.new(ldap_options)
```

Here is my LDAP config:

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
required_groups:
- CN=GROUP1,OU=Users,OU=mysite,DC=ad,DC=com

## Environment

development:
  host: mysite.com
  port: 389
  attribute: sAMAccountName
  base: dc=ad,dc=com
  admin_user: user
  admin_password: password
  ssl: false
  <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS

 production:
  host: mysite.com
  port: 389
  attribute: sAMAccountName
  base: dc=ad,dc=com
  admin_user: user
  admin_password: password
  ssl: false
  <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

Any thoughts on why this only does this in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! In my LDAP.yml file the production connection section was indented by one space. This was causing it to not load the config correctly. Aligning the productions ection to the left all the way fixed it. Everything is working now.